# How to reduce file_get_contents excution time

Tags: php, url

I am using `file_get_contents` to fetch title from the link, but it takes around 20 - 30 sec to execute. Is there an easy and fast way to fetch?

Update: I tried this code which brings everything including html

```
$page = fread(fopen($url, "r"), 1000);   // first 2KB
$titleStart = strpos($page,'<title>')+7;
$titleLength = strpos($page,'</title>')-$titleStart;
$meta['title'] = substr($page,$titleStart,$titleLength);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For retrieving remote pages, the time depends mostly on the connection speed,  latency and the remote server. There is not much you can do about these things, and using an alternative HTTP retrieval method will help only inmeasurably.

If however the remote page is quite large then it makes sense to fetch it only partially. Instead of file_get_contents to download the complete page, try:

```
$page = fread(fopen($url, "r"), 2048);   // first 2KB
```

For extraction use this rather than your substr method:

```
preg_match('#<title>(.*?)</title>#', $page, $match);
$meta["title"] = $match[1];
```

Comment: '$page = fread(fopen($url, "r"), 1000);   // first 2KB
$titleStart=strpos($page,'<title>')+7;
$titleLength=strpos($page,'</title>')-$titleStart;
$meta['title']=substr($page,$titleStart,$titleLength);' i tried this code its fast but which bring back the contents not the title

Comment: Then make it 4KB or 8KB. Don't know the details of your usage.

Comment: i just want to print the META Title of the link.. but it's bring the entire html code

Comment: You need to explain better what you want. Just use the extraction function that you already have.

Answer (score 3):

You could try curl (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), or caching the answer if it doesn't change regularly.

Your problem is most likely due to network latency, and a large part of that is controlled by the site you're pulling your data from.  A server that's geographically closer to the host could help.

Comment: Agreed. cURL is much faster than `file_get_contents` or `fopen` in these situations.

Answer (score 1):

you're best bet for a file that may be requested often is to cache it.

keep a `cache` folder on your server and as long as the files you are requesting do not change often you can just check the last modification time of your cached version of the file with `filemtime()` and if the time is more than 24 hours old, you can request the remote file

Answer (score 0):

curl functions is the solution, because there are CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT in curl, but there is only stream_set_timeout(connection timeout) in file_get_contents, fopen etc.